# Валидация на максимальное количество символов в XML для уже созданного XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, валидация

Добрый день(утро, вечер) сообщество!

Дано:
Есть уже созданный XmlReader, который зачитывает довольно большой по объему XML. Получение SOAP сообщения через WCF от веб-сервиса в Mono. Проблема в том, что нужно сделать валидацию до десериализации, так как получается большой объект при достаточно небольших ресурсах и происходит падение системы. Опция maxReceivedMessageSize для конфигурации WCF-сервиса в Mono не работает.

Задача:
Сделать валидацию на максимальное количество символов, не вычитывая весь XML (например методом ReadOuterXml()). Другими словами, вычитывать последовательно и если будет достигнуто максимальное количество то выкинуть исключение. При этом должна быть возможность вычитать XML повторно.

Я попробовал следующий пример, но он не работает для повторно созданного ридера:

```
string xml = "<X><Y><Z></Z><Z></Z><Z></Z></Y></X>";

var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                {
                    MaxCharactersInDocument = 10
                };

try
{
    using(var sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)) // считаем, что данный ридер уже задан, т.е. это внешний объект
        {
            var x = XElement.Load(xr);
            using(var xr2 = XmlReader.Create(x.CreateReader(), settings))
            {
                while(xr.Read()){} // валидация не работает
            }
            using(var xr3 = XmlReader.Create(x.CreateReader(), settings))
            {
                xr3.MoveToContent();
                Console.WriteLine(xr3.ReadOuterXml()); // повторное зачитывание работает
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (XmlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Копирую из своего комментария: Поправьте меня, если я не прав, но насколько я понимаю, XElement.Load(xr) не вычитывает весь документ, а создает обертку на ридером и вычитывание происходит при необходимости. Уж как он его перечитывает повторно я затрудняюсь сказать, поэтому было бы интересно послушать мнение знающих людей.

Один из уважаемых участников обсуждения утверждает, что XElement.Load(xr) вычитывает весь документ. Значит нужно искать другое решение. Получается, что единственным решением является и вычитывание и валидирование одновременно. Но вопрос, как это сделать используя XmlReader, который не я создаю?

Вариант, который к моему удивлению не работает:

```
using(var sr = new StringReader(xml))
{
    using(var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)) // считаем, что данный ридер уже задан, т.е. это внешний объект
    {
        using(var xr2 = XmlReader.Create(xr, settings))
        {
            while(xr2.Read()){} // валидация не работает
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Предлагаю сделать 1) Stream-обвёртку к стриму загрузки, как только счётчик байтов превысит лимит (для стрима без размера) или размер стрима больше - отсечь , или стоп, 2) при загрузке данных на сайт можно прочесть Content-Length, и сразу заблокировать анализ xml.

Comment: @nick_n_a у меня нет доступа к загрузке, есть уже готовый XmlReader на входе

Comment: Попробуйте установить  xr.Settings MaxCharactersInDocument = 10, посмотреть что в Settings.

Comment: @nick_n_a пробовал. The 'XmlReaderSettings.MaxCharactersInDocument' property is read only and cannot be set.

Comment: Теоретически текущую позицию в стриме можно вытащить через рефлекшен. Но проблема в том, что XmlReader после валидации никак не перемотать на начало. Как вариант, если вы используете http-привязки в wcf, то можно вытащить из сообщения заголовок content-length.

Comment: Спасибо @kmv, я думал над вариантом о привязках в WCF. Пока оставил его как план "Б".

Comment: Если это SOAP, можно вклинится между обработчиком SOAP и IIS, например можно обьявить "ashx" или "asax" програмный обработчик страницы IHttpContext. Считать stream (или проверить content-length) можно протестить его regexp-ом. А потом в случае успеха передать IHttpContext на стандартный Soap-Обработчик System.Web.Compilation.WebServiceBuildProvider (если это asax перехватчик перенаправит сам). В худшем случае прийдётся читать xml в текстовый буфер, а уже на буфер создать ридер.

Comment: такой вот вопрос: а откуда вообще у вас берется неподконтрольный вам XmlReader при работе с WCF?

Comment: @PavelMayorov. Есть ServiceContract, аргументы и возвращаемые значения всех методов являются объектами (MessageContract) сериализуемыми при помощи Xml сериализации. Из метода ReadXml и берется не подконтрольный XmlReader. И все было бы хорошо, если бы в Mono работала опция maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000". Но к сожалению у них еще не дошли руки до этой опции :(

Answer (score 1):

Ваша задача какая-то странная. Вы пишите одновременно что не хотите вычитывать весь XML - и сами же требуете возможность повторного чтения. А это - взаимоисключающие требования.

К примеру, ваш же код - `var x = XElement.Load(xr);` - это уже вычитывание всего документа. После этого даже не надо делать `xr3.ReadOuterXml()`, можно просто взять `x.ToString().Length` :)

---

Если вы получаете сообщение через WCF - то не проще ли правильно настроить ограничение на размер сообщения в привязке?

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mySuperBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: к сожалению в Mono опция maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" не работает

Comment: Поправьте меня, если я не прав, но насколько я понимаю, XElement.Load(xr) не вычитывает весь документ, а создает обертку на ридером и вычитывание происходит при необходимости. Уж как он его перечитывает повторно я затрудняюсь сказать, поэтому было бы интересно послушать мнение знающих людей.

Comment: @SeriousOrange вы ошибаетесь. `Load` вычитывает документ полностью

Comment: @ PavelMayorov в таком случае мой пример, мне не подходит :) Нужно искать другое решение. Получается, что единственным решением является и вычитывание и валидирование одновременно. Но вопрос, как это сделать используя XmlReader, который не я создаю?

Comment: @SeriousOrange обернуть его в другой, примерно как вы и делали

Comment: я пробовал это делать. Но к моему удивлению. валидация на максимальное количество символов (MaxCharactersInDocument) перестает работать для ридера, обернутого поверх данного. При этом валидация схемы работает. :(

Answer (score 0):

Попробую извратится, вариант с переливанием из ридера в память и обратно, с мелким ограничением.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;



public class Demo {

static void Main() {

string xml = "<ekjfhkhefkjhwgkhgew><Y><Z></Z><Z></Z><Z></Z></Y></ekjfhkhefkjhwgkhgew>";
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

try
{

    using(StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        using(XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr)) // считаем, что данный ридер уже задан, т.е. это внешний объект
        {
//----------------
System.IO.MemoryStream mem = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx
    using (XmlWriter writer=XmlWriter.Create(mem,new XmlWriterSettings() ))
    {


        // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
        while (xr.Read())
        {

          writer.Flush();
           if (mem.Position > 10) throw new System.Xml.XmlException("Xml size limit exceed");
           Console.WriteLine(mem.Position); // Информация

            switch (xr.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    writer.WriteStartElement(xr.Name);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    writer.WriteString(xr.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(xr.Name, xr.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    writer.WriteComment(xr.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                    break;
            }
        }

    }


XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(mem);
// Продолжение сюда
//---------------------------------------------------------

        }
    }
}
catch (XmlException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}

   }

   };
```

Стрим тут уже участвует, если немного помучатся, вожможно можно написать свою обвёртку

Comment: Cпасибо за идею. Но есть ограничения по памяти, поэтому ваш вариант не подойдет.

Comment: Тогда вместо Memory-stream пишите свой stream который анализирует xml (Написать обвёртку IStream -> IStream-> XmlReader c одной стороны заталкивать данные с другой читать). Если не проще счётчики данных поставить.

Comment: А, я не понял про обертку над стримом сразу :) А это уже интересная идея, спасибо!

Comment: Но и эту идею оставлю пока как план "В", так как она чревата неожиданными багами.